# Not all programs that are install-able are appearing in Ubuntu Software

Tags: 20.04, software-center

So I installed Ubuntu and thought I'd try out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNX7HgcWqHc). When I was following along I noticed that not all programs are listed in the Ubuntu Software Application.

Does anyone have ideas on why it could be? I tried installing Synaptic Package Installer and Dconf Editor. Did they get removed? The video is only one month old.

Comment: Both Synaptic and Dconf Editor are listed properly in my Ubuntu Software, and neither has been removed from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I've just made a fresh install, updated, and indeed they don't show.

Comment: I installed `gnome-software` and they show. ¿What's the difference between them???

Comment: Ubuntu software center/store has been a bit on the iffy side since it came out years ago.  Most of the time it works okay now, but it never has seem to be the best.  Had to move to appgrid when it first came out because it was so slow.