# Ubuntu Softwarecenter is not loading

Tags: 20.04, software-center

I installed fresh Ubuntu 20.04. The Softwarecenter is not loading.

I did `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade.

This is how it looks if I open it:

[image]

Or like this if I try to install a program over a dev file:

[image]

Problem remains after restarts.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Related [Not all programs that are install-able are appearing in Ubuntu Software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274676/not-all-programs-that-are-install-able-are-appearing-in-ubuntu-software#comment2160263_1274676) and [What is the difference between 'gnome-software' and 'ubuntu-software'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769129/what-is-the-difference-between-gnome-software-and-ubuntu-software). I went directly to  `gnome-software` instead of trying to fix the faulty ubuntu software.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the GNOME Software Center?

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-software
```

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-software*
```

Comment: Ubuntu software and gnome software are two different programs.

Comment: Not really. If they were the same software they should behave the same, wich they don't, and wouldn't be *two different packages*. I use 20.04 and had to replace US for GS. Uninstalling GS wouldn't make a difference, since what OP runs is US.